# How to iterate through each property element in API response in Katalon studio?

Tags: groovy, katalon-studio, web-api-testing

I'm writing test script in katalon studio to verify response body of the API.My response body is of format:

```
{
  "status": "Success",
  "correlationCode": "1234-5678",
  "type": {
    "id": 51247,
    "name": "Student",
  },
  "data": {
    "name": "Sara Nieves",
    "gender": "Female",
    "dob": "1995-08-06",
    "libraryCard": {
      "id": "11178",
      "type": "Seniors"
    },
    "qualifications": [
      {
        "id": "45650986546",
        "name": "Graduate Certificate in Environmental Engineering Management"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to verify that none of the elements return 'null' value. Since, the elements returned for the API response are not static(meaning name, gender etc might not get returned every time) therefore, i can't use something like "data.name" to verify if it has null value. So, i want a generic way to loop through each and every attribute returned and check if its value is returned as null or not.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `response.each{k,v-> assert v!=null }` but create a recursive function

Comment: @daggett Can you please explain how this works?...i don't understand what 'k & v' refer to over here and if i try this solution it gives me exception as:


java.lang.Object k, java.lang.Object v -> ... })
2019-09-30 12:43:45.315 ERROR c.k.k.core.main.WSVerificationExecutor   - ? Verification FAILED.
Reason:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: WSVerification1569811424284$_run_closure1.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ResponseObject) values: [200 1 KB]
22572.groovy:21)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the error message:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: WSVerification1569811424284$_run_closure1.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ResponseObject) values: [200 1 KB] 22572.groovy:21)

I assume your response object type: [com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ResponseObject](https://docs.katalon.com/javadoc/com/kms/katalon/core/testobject/ResponseObject.html)

The code to parse response as json and validate it:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

/**
 * the recursive method to validate that json object does not have null values 
 * @param obj  - the parsed json object (sequence of maps and lists)
 * @param path - a variable to know where the error occurred in json data.
 */
void assertNoNullValue(Object obj, String path='ROOT'){
    //the main assertion
    assert obj!=null : "value in json could not be null: $path"

    if(obj instanceof Map){
        //iterate each key-value in map and validate the value recursively
        obj.each{k,v-> assertNoNullValue(v,path+".$k") }
    } else if(obj instanceof List){
        //iterate each value in list and validate the value recursively
        obj.eachWithIndex{v,i-> assertNoNullValue(v,path+"[$i]") }
    }
}

def response = ...
assert response.isJsonContentType()
def responseText = response.getResponseText()

//parse body
def data = new JsonSlurper().parseText(responseText)
assertNoNullValue(data)
```

Comment: Thanks @daggett. That's exactly what i wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not as precise as the one suggested by @dagget, but it is a quick check:

```
def response = '''
{
  "status": "Success",
  "correlationCode": "1234-5678",
  "type": {
    "id": 51247,
    "name": "Student",
  },
  "data": {
    "name": "Sara Nieves",
    "gender": "femmina",
    "dob": "1995-08-06",
    "libraryCard": {
      "id": "11178",
      "type": "Seniors"
    },
    "qualifications": [
      {
        "id": "45650986546",
        "name": "Graduate Certificate in Environmental Engineering Management"
      }
    ]
  }
}
'''
assert !response.contains("null")
```

Comment: Hi, I wanted to clarify that whenever any attribute returns null value, it is displayed in response in this format : "name" : null i.e. without qoutes....will the syntax you gave cover this scenario?, i tried your solution and it works if i deliberately set value of some field as null and it is returned as "name" : "null" (i.e. with qoutes)

Comment: This checks for the substring, so it will work for "null" and null.

Comment: Thanks @mate. Although its not the solution i required. it surely increased my knowledge